# Canvas overlapped by scene objects

Tags: unity, gui

I am doing a space game and I have a little problem when doing the GUI.

As you can see here: [image] the objects from the scene overlap the text from the GUI.

From what I've seen on other topics, it seems that using Camera screen space any object closer than the Plane distance overlaps, but if I decrease the plane distance I can't see the canvas.

I've also tried setting the screen space to overlay, which should fix this, but then the GUI is not shown in the screen.

Anybody knows how to prevent the overlapping or at least what should I do for being able to use screen space overlay? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you change **render mode** to **screen space overlay** then **target display** is not set to **Display 1**. So do the following I hope this will resolved the issue.

1. Change Canvas render mode to "screen space to overlay".
2. Change Target Display to "Display 1".
3. Make sure one or more UI object in the Canvas is enabled. i.e a button or txt.

[image]"

Comment: Hi, yes that's what I tried to do. It turns out that it was working but the text color changed to black and I wasn't able to see it.

Comment: Yeah, that solved it, the material of the text was a wrong one. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I am glad i was helpful.

Comment: @Hector you may want to add your own answer showing how you determined the material was wrong and how you fixed it. This could be helpful to other users troubleshooting a similar problem.

Comment: Sure, as I said in a previous comment, the text color changed to black when I switched the render mode to screen space overlay. It turned out that I had used the standard material with emission (and fading rendering) I use por the lásers for the GUI texts. As soon as I realized and switched to the default material the problem was fixed.

Comment: why was your canvas **order in layer** set to -1?